# Multi-player games rating method: how to improve Python code and get more speed

Tags: python, arrays, pandas

I am making an ELO like rating system for online games players.
ELO is used for one-v-one games whereas I want to hae multi-player games.
Here I Modify an ordinal range to give more weight to the winner and close finishers by using an exponential function
Events have an id, 'event_id' and a field size, 'fsize'
Players have an id, 'player_id' and a finishing position, 'finish'

The code runs and produces values that look reasonable but it is too slow when applied to large amounts of data eg 100k events.
My Python skills are not up to seeing how I can improve this code, any assistance appreciated!

## A toy dataset

```
dict = {'event_id': [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4],
        'player_id': [1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,5],
        'fsize': [3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5],
        'finish': [1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,5]}
df = pd.DataFrame(dict)

base = 1.5 # for an exponential score set this greater than 1
# n is number of players in an event
# For example the exponential scores using a base of 1.5 and n of 3 and printing the values
np.array([base ** (n - p) - 1 for p in range(1, n + 1)])[0]

print(np.array([base ** (5 - p) - 1 for p in range(1, 5 + 1)])[0])
print(np.array([base ** (5 - p) - 1 for p in range(1, 5 + 1)])[1])
print(np.array([base ** (5 - p) - 1 for p in range(1, 5 + 1)])[2])

#pd.set_option('mode.chained_assignment', None)
df['score'] = 0 # initialize the score
for j in range(0, df.shape[0]):   
    df['score'][j] = np.array([base ** (df['fsize'][j] - p) - 1 for p in range(1, df['fsize'][j] + 1)])[df['finish'][j]-1]
    # normalize the score to so that sum() of 'score' for each 'event_id' is 1
    df['score_sum'] = df['score'].groupby(df['event_id']).transform('sum')
    df['score_norm'] = round(df.score/df['score_sum'],4)

print(df)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this code is more optimized and you can run it fast and have same approach:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Create the DataFrame
data = {'event_id': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4],
        'player_id': [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        'fsize': [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5],
        'finish': [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

base = 1.5

# Calculate the exponential scores using a vectorized approach
df['score'] = base ** (df['fsize'] - df['finish']) - 1

# Calculate the sum of scores for each event
df['score_sum'] = df.groupby('event_id')['score'].transform('sum')

# Normalize the scores
df['score_norm'] = df['score'] / df['score_sum']
df['score_norm'] = df['score_norm'].round(4)

print(df)
```

Comment: Thanks Omid and thank you for your very quick response! A wonderful solution and very much faster than my effort!

Answer (score 2):

We can broadcast the score calculation operation instead of looping over the rows individually.

The build-in rounding is actually faster than the `pandas` one:

```
def builtin_rounding(data: pd.DataFrame):
    df["score"] = base ** (df["fsize"] - df["finish"]) - 1
    df["score_sum"] = df["score"].groupby(df["event_id"]).transform("sum")
    df["score_norm"] = round((df.score / df["score_sum"]),4)
    return df
```

Let's profile the various functions:

```
def op_approach(data):
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    base = 1.5 # for an exponential score set this greater than 1
    df['score'] = 0 # initialize the score
    for j in range(0, df.shape[0]):   
        df['score'][j] = np.array([base ** (df['fsize'][j] - p) - 1 for p in range(1, df['fsize'][j] + 1)])[df['finish'][j]-1]
        # normalize the score to so that sum() of 'score' for each 'event_id' is 1
        df['score_sum'] = df['score'].groupby(df['event_id']).transform('sum')
        df['score_norm'] = round(df.score/df['score_sum'],4)
    return(df)
```

```
def full_pandas(data: pd.DataFrame):
    df["score"] = base ** (df["fsize"] - df["finish"]) - 1
    df["score_sum"] = df["score"].groupby(df["event_id"]).transform("sum")
    df["score_norm"] = (df.score / df["score_sum"]).round(4)
    return df
```

```
import random

def setup(N):
    event_id = []
    player_id = []
    fsize = []
    finish = []

    for i in range(N):
        num_players = random.randint(2, N//2)
        event_id.extend([i+1] * num_players)
        player_id.extend(list(range(1, num_players+1)))
        fsize.extend([num_players] * num_players)
        finish.extend(list(range(1, num_players+1)))

    data = {
        'event_id': event_id,
        'player_id': player_id,
        'fsize': fsize,
        'finish': finish
    }
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)

    return [df]
import random
import warnings

from performance_measurement import run_performance_comparison

warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
data_size = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 100, 200]  

approaches = [
    op_approach,
    full_pandas,
    builtin_rounding,
]
run_performance_comparison(approaches, data_size, setup=setup, number_of_repetitions=1)
```

Both `versions` with the direct `Series` construction instead of a row-by-row approach outperform by orders of magnitude as expected:

[image]

The built-in `round` outperforms `pd.Series.round`:

[image]

Profiling code:

```
import timeit
from functools import partial

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from typing import List, Dict, Callable

from contextlib import contextmanager
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.transforms as mtransforms
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
import numpy as np


@contextmanager
def data_provider(data_size, setup=lambda N: N, teardown=lambda: None):
    data = setup(data_size)
    yield data
    teardown(*data)


def run_performance_comparison(approaches: List[Callable],
                               data_size: List[int],
                               *,
                               setup=lambda N: [N],
                               teardown=lambda *N: None,
                               number_of_repetitions=5,
                               title='Performance Comparison',
                               data_name='N',
                               yscale='log',
                               xscale='log'):
       approach_times: Dict[Callable, List[float]] = {approach: [] for approach in approaches}
    for N in data_size:
        with data_provider(N, setup, teardown) as data:
            print(f'Running performance comparison for {data_name}={N}')
            for approach in approaches:
                function = partial(approach, *data)
                approach_time = min(timeit.Timer(function).repeat(repeat=number_of_repetitions, number=1))
                approach_times[approach].append(approach_time)

    for approach in approaches:
        plt.plot(data_size, approach_times[approach], label=approach.__name__)
    plt.yscale(yscale)
    plt.xscale(xscale)

    plt.xlabel(data_name)
    plt.ylabel('Execution Time (seconds)')
    plt.title(title)
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()
```

Comment: Sebastian, Thank you for this work through! Quite a bit for me to study in your code, much appreciated!